# Basic copy and paste Macro

Tags: excel

I am a basic excel. I have tried making a Macro to do a basic task but I can't seem to figure it out, can anyone help please!

I basically just want to copy a word in front of numerous titles in separate cells and then add the data from an adjacent cell to the end. For example

```
A1 - Happy Birthday A-2 WC367
B1 - Congratulations B-2 WC675
C1 - Good Luck C-2 WC542
```

etc etc.

Now I want to add a supplier name (WOOD) in front of all these titles and then copy the data fro A-2,B-2,C-2 onto the end of this title.

They should end up looking like this:

```
A-1 Wood Happy Birthday WC367
B-1 Wood Congratulations WC675
C-1 Wood Good Luck WC542
```

I have tried making a Marco but it just copies the data from the Macro I made into each one rather than using the data from the relevant cells. I have ended up having to copy and paste the code into each one and adding a symbol at the beginning and then doing a find and replace all which all seems very long winded.

Comment: Show the code that you have at the moment

Comment: Why don't you put a formula in `D1` something like `="Wood " & A1 & " " & B1 & " " & C1` and then fill down?

Answer (score 0):

You can just type in `A3 = CONCATENATE("Wood ",A1," ",A2)` and drag the formula to the right.

Or the following code:

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, LastCol)).Value = "=CONCATENATE(""Wood "",R[-2]C,"" "",R[-1]C)"
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, LastCol)).Value = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, LastCol)).Value
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, LastCol)).ClearContents
End Sub
```